# javascript upload image using url (image already on internet, different domain)

Tags: javascript, jquery, image, upload

I need to upload an image to my site, using either a drag and drop'd image (from the local machine, already works), or drag and drop'd from a other website (doesn't work).

I am struggling to get the image being drop'd url and due to that I cannot process the image to be uploaded.

I have considered using the jquery.load(), but will still need the image url.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

using

```
e.dataTransfer.getData('text')
```

got me my url, no idea how I missed this!

I then just passed the URL to an asp.net page which handled the rest.

Answer (score 0):

WOuld be tough to retrieve image at client side from different url as Cross Domain scripting is not allowed in many browsers. So you could not do a ajax request to download the url. What you could probably do is, use the URL to make server side get request and download the image

Or you could add a dynamic image tag from server side with url given by the user.

Comment: Yea, I don't mind posting the url to a different page and then handling the download on the server side.  However I can't get the url when I drop it into my dropbox container. using this  http://www.github.com/weixiyen/jquery-filedrop

Comment: Ok,

so I don't know how I missed this, but this gets me the URL of the dropped image.

I'll mark it as the answer in 8 hours, unless you post it and I mark as answer.  Thanx

     e.dataTransfer.getData('text')